# Data Source window is disbaled and not working, WinForm project using DataSource

Tags: c#, winforms, datasource

So the weirdest thing happened to my winForm project!

Half way through it, the data source window became disabled and now not only it doesn't show any content, but its buttons are also disabled and when i right click on its surface, it displays "no commands available"!

I must say that :

1) server explorer works just fine and is able to show the contents of my MSSQLServer database.

2) this problem is only happening for this special project, since i created a new winForm project and the data source window works just fine there!

3) this is not an issue of the data source window not being found or its displaying button in (View -> Other Windows -> Data Source) being disabled.

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me out here because i haven't had any luck with google and i'm totally lost! Thanks all in advance

Comment: Hi welcome to stack overflow. Could you add some line breaks to your question and correct the grammar?

Comment: @dwjohnston I hope that's better ...